# How to add child dynamically into particular group in expandableListview?

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            try {
                               expenses = editText.getText().toString();

                                int a = (int)getGroupId(groupPosition);
                                Log.e("group id",String.valueOf(a));

                               obj.prepareListData(expenses,(int) getGroupId(groupPosition));

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("123", e.toString());
                            }

                        }
                    });

public void prepareListData(String s, int position) {

   List<String>  expenses = new ArrayList<String>();

    expenses.add(s);

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(position), expenses);
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

}
```

Here i want to add different expenses into different group(header) but expenses gets overwrite to previous one into header.

How can i add different multiple values into different group(header)? please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't instanciate ExpandableListAdapter every time you change your data.

You should only modify your data list and then call the listAdapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this will automatically apply the data changes!

Comment: Welcome, you can tick my answer then ;-)